# How to automate or handle from code for error 405 HTTP Verb Not Allowed – ASP.Net Core 3.1, instead of updating web.config for every deployment

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-3.1

How to automate or handle from code for error **405 HTTP Verb Not Allowed** – ASP.Net Core 3.1., instead of  updating web.config for every deployment.

The solution suggested on almost all question of same kind is

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This solution works,however I need to update web.config for every deployment. How to automate this process?

Answer (score -1):

Disable the WebDAV Publishing feature in Windows.

This is the easiest solution if WebDAV is not desired for any website running on IIS on the server.

**Windows Server Editions:**

Open the Server Manager and select "Manage", "Remove Roles and Features", jump to the "Server Roles" section and uncheck the following option:

Web Server (IIS) > Web Server > Common HTTP Features > WebDAV Publishing

Select "Next" until you can select "Remove" on the Confirmation section. You may need to restart the server for the change to take effect.

**Windows Desktop Editions:**

Open a Windows Explorer window and navigate to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features.  Select the Turn Windows features on or off option in the menu on the left.  Uncheck the following option: Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Common HTTP Features > WebDAV Publishing. Click OK. You may need to restart the server for the change to take effect.